# Select distinct occurrences of substring from a column in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find a portion of distinct email addresses (`@gmail.com`) 
in a column which contains a paragraph of text which may contain one or more instances of the email address.  My table contains several rows with paragraphs and I am trying to identify the unique email address that use `@gmail.com`.

Thanks in advance

Table A

```
script_id  script
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          Sending information to a@gmail.com, please also send to a@gmail.com          
           and b@gmail.com
2          Sending information to a@gmail.com, b@gmail.com.
2
```

Comment: Sorry but this question seems to be destined to be closed unless you: a) provide example data, b) show what code have you tried so far, c) show the structure of the table where the data lies.

Comment: Can you please post your current Query.

Comment: SO is not a free coding service!!!  You write your query.  If it doesn't work, we can help.  Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a split function on the spaces in a paragraph, this is trivial.

[**Check The Online Demo Here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=38cb2a4c50e49474c0b2c0e973b03e41)

```
declare @table table (p varchar(4000))
insert into @table
values
('this paragrapsh contains one@gmail.com and duplicate one@gmail.com and one.two@gmail.com and one_two_three@gmail.com. How neat is that? Pretty neat eh!?')


select distinct 
    --case statement removed periods from end of email for when it's at the end of a sentence
    case when right(x.Item,1) != 'm' then left(x.Item,len(x.Item) - 1) else x.Item end
from @table t
cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(p,' ') x
where x.Item like '%@gmail.com%'
```

[**Here is the function from Jeff Moden**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K] (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!

RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN

/* "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)*/

  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
```

**Using Your Newly Supplied Data** With a [DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9a9b34bb1006c869922fa5bf35ecaa2b)

```
declare @table table (script_id int identity(1,1), script varchar(4000))
insert into @table
values
('Sending information to a@gmail.com, please also send to a@gmail.com          
           and b@gmail.com'),
('Sending information to a@gmail.com, b@gmail.com.')


select distinct 
    --case statement removed periods from end of email for when it's at the end of a sentence
    case when right(x.Item,1) != 'm' then left(x.Item,len(x.Item) - 1) else x.Item end
from @table t
cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(script,' ') x
where x.Item like '%@gmail.com%'
```